# My plugin won't load because of a "Wrong architecture"

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

I'm developing a plugin for a 32bit software. 
The coding process is almost done, but to test it, I've got to load my plugin into the software.

There is no warning/error when compiling, but the plugin won't load.

Using the mac console logs, I found out that the error was :

> ```
> > 17/08/2015 12:04:51,271 Hidden[7518]: Error loading
> > /Library/Application
> > Support/Hidden/Plugins/MultiUsersPreferences.hiddenplugin/Contents/MacOS/MultiUsersPreferences:
> > dlopen(/Library/Application
> > Support/Hidden/Plugins/MultiUsersPreferences.hiddenplugin/Contents/MacOS/MultiUsersPreferences,
> > 265): no suitable image found.  Did find:   /Library/Application
> > Support/Hidden/Plugins/MultiUsersPreferences.hiddenplugin/Contents/MacOS/MultiUsersPreferences:
> > mach-o, but wrong architecture
> ```

I tried to change the Architectures (build settings) to

```
Universal (32/64-bit Intel) (x86_64, i386) - $(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_64_BIT)
```

But the same error keep poppin' up.

So far, I did not find any solution to set it right, I don't know Xcode enough to do it by my own, does anyone could give me a hint ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the project settings, set the architecture to just 32-bit:

[image]

Using the '[file](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/file.1.html)' command, you can check the binary's architecture. For example:

```
$ file /Applications/Calculator.app/Contents/MacOS/Calculator
/Applications/Calculator.app/Contents/MacOS/Calculator: Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, change "Build Active Architecture Only" to "No".  You're probably building a debug build, which by default on 64-bit machines builds only a 64-bit slice.